# Eu tenho uma dúvida sobre construtores default herdados

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, ponteiro, herança

Eu estou com dúvida ao tentar melhorar um exercicio de POO aqui..

(-) = sem

Eu tenho a classe PAI com dois constructors (um é default). Na classe FILHO tenho mais dois constructors (no-default). Na definição de um desses constructors há duas condicionais que inicializa os contructors da classe pai, cada um em determinada situação.

O problema é que quando instancio um novo objeto do tipo filho, com parametros para iniciar contructor pai com parametros. Ele simplesmente salta o constructor no-default e controi o default, retornando assim um valor indesejado.

O código simplificado é esse aqui:

Header file--

```
class Pai{
int c;
public:
   int getC() //que retorna C
   Pai(){ c=100; }
   Pai(int arg){ c=arg; }
};

class Filho: public Pai{
public:
   Filho(int arg1)//esse não precisa atentar-se
   Filho(int arg1, int arg2);
};
```

Definição dos contructor do filho----

```
Filho::Filho(int arg1){ //esse aqui é so representativo mas existe }

Filho::Filho(int arg1, arg2){
   if(arg2>0)
      Pai(arg2); //No-Default constructor 
   else{ Pai(); //Default constructor }
}
```

Instanciando objeto de filho--

```
Filho *f1 = new Filho(3, 5); 

cout << "O valor de arg2 é: " << f1->getC() << endl;
```

Out -> 100 (retornou o construtor padrão)

MAS. Quando eu instancio diretamente para o pai é retornado o valor desejado.

Por que ele está chamando o construtor padrão do pai sem eu mandar?

Já pesquisei em vários lugares isso e não achei, espero que eu encontre a resposta aqui :/

Comment: Esse exemplo tem vários erros de sintaxe, desde tipos de parametros não escritos, chaves incorretas, etc.. Tem ele escrito dessa forma no seu código ?

Comment: Não. Esse foi só um exemplo, desculpe se não me atentei à alguns detalhes no exemplo

Comment: Esse é meu código só pra constar tá. Só que de forma mais simples..

Comment: Confirme a sintaxe que está a utilizar de chamar a classe base, que não me parece que exista, e o problema provavelmente reside ai. Normalmente é chamado assim `Derivada() : Base() { //implementação }`

Comment: Irei verificar..

Comment: Essa sintaxe apresentada por você eu já conhecia mas sempre deu erro aqui.. (resumindo: eu teste e deu erro de sintaxe)

Comment: Mas olha só.. mesmo que isto estivesse certo. Eu não teria que ter um construtor padrão na class derivada? sendo que Derivada( ) //( ) default constructor

Comment: " eu já conhecia mas sempre deu erro aqui" É porque não implementou da forma correta. "Eu não teria que ter um construtor padrão na class derivada? " Não é obrigatório, mas no fim depende de como está a utilizar/instanciar os objetos dessa classe.

Comment: ensine-me como implementar da forma correta, porfavor!

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é que você não está modificando os valores da sua classe.

```
Filho::Filho(int arg1, arg2){
if(arg2>0)
  Pai(arg2); //<- aqui está o erro, uma nova instancia da classe pai é criada
   else{ Pai(); //Default constructor }
}
```

Ao fazer isso você está na verdade criando uma nova instancia da classe pai. Neste caso a solução seria usar um método ao invés de uma construtora (ex: setC(int c))

Comment: Então quando eu instancio o Pai novamente eu automaticamente chamo o constructor default?